# Find fourth coordinates given other three points

Tags: vector-analysis, coordinate-systems

Find coordinates of $D$, given coordinates of $A,B,C$, torsion angle and angle between $BCD$.

Is there any other way other than the torsion angle equation, 
 $$n_1=\langle b_1\times b_2\rangle \;\text{ and }\; n_2=\langle b_2\times b_3\rangle $$
 $$\phi = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{n_1.n_2}{\|n|\ \|m\|} \right)\tag{A}  $$

I will have to write a program to calculate the co-ordinates, so the eqn $(A)$ is bit problematic to use, since $D$ contains the variables here. Can you suggest a better way?

Comment: Hi user1437834, I'm not sure if I got the $-1$ right in my edit. Do please check it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a long wait, I found my answer. The forum was of literally no help, since no one could give the solution.

Please find the details in this paper: [Molecular Distance Geometry Problem](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/mdgpquantum.pdf)